# How to tell a panel that it is being resized when using wx.aui

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using wx.aui to build my user interface. I'm defining a class that inherits from wx.Panel and I need to change the content of that panel when its window pane is resized.

I'm using code very similar to the code below (which is a modified version of sample code found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523363/how-do-i-layout-a-3-pane-window-using-wxpython/532873#532873)).

My question is: is there a wx.Panel method being called behind the scenes by the AuiManager that I can overload? If not, how can my ControlPanel object know that it's being resized?

For instance, if I run this code and drag up the horizontal divider between the upper and lower panes on the right, how is the upper right panel told that its size just changed?

```
import wx
import wx.aui

class ControlPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.mgr = wx.aui.AuiManager(self)

        leftpanel = ControlPanel(self, -1, size = (200, 150))
        rightpanel = ControlPanel(self, -1, size = (200, 150))
        bottompanel = ControlPanel(self, -1, size = (200, 150))

        self.mgr.AddPane(leftpanel, wx.aui.AuiPaneInfo().Bottom())
        self.mgr.AddPane(rightpanel, wx.aui.AuiPaneInfo().Left().Layer(1))
        self.mgr.AddPane(bottompanel, wx.aui.AuiPaneInfo().Center().Layer(2))

        self.mgr.Update()


class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyFrame(None, -1, '07_wxaui.py')
        frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the wx.Panel docs, wx.Panel.Layout is called "automatically by the default EVT_SIZE handler when the window is resized."

EDIT: However, the above doesn't work as I would expect, so try manually binding EVT_SIZE:

```
class ControlPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.OnResize)

    def OnResize(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Resizing"
```